# Testing strategy when working with external webservices

Tags: java, testing, testng, mockito, twitter4j

I often have to code against Twitter, and now against other Web Service APIs that I do not control.

I've tried to write test cases but it seems too difficult as:

1. I am bound to the speed of something I cannot control (the web-service).
2. I cannot control the state of the web service (cannot delete an account, tweet, and restart)

For folks facing similar situations, I'd like to find out the solutions they've devised.

PS: I'm familiar with mock objects but I'd like to get more specific lessons learned -- for example I use a library to talk to Twitter (Twitter4J) which, when last I looked does not allow me to substitute a mock object for the Twitter Service.

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't done it myself. but I know that tools like Fiddler and the BrowserMob proxy have support for intercepting HTTP traffic and sending back responses directly. I think they both have APIs where you could potentially change the rules on the fly, but I'm not positive. You could probably configure the tool once and then start/stop it for your tests. You'd need a way to specify what response you're looking for somehow, but this is the direction I'd start investigating first if I were faced with a similar challenge.

Comment: Build a wrapper around the library and mock the wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my projects (which rely on a variety of external web services) I've focused my testing on failure events.  So when building a unit test for Facebook Connect I tried to pass junk data to my web service response processing methods to make sure that I could handle the service changing underneath me.  Successful event testing wasn't something I put into a unit test because it creates so much cruft (like events in a timeline).  A possible work around to this are to create a test account in your intended service and point your unit tests to that ID.  If you make sure that your web service posting code doesn't include hard coded IDs (I like to create `<Service>Config` classes that are passed to `<Service>Methods` classes like `FacebookMethods.auth(FacebookConfig config, String uid)`) this lets me create a TestConfig for operations that will modify a service in a way that can't be undone or shouldn't be seen publicly).

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for the input, but based on your comment I still don't have a way to build a complete regression test suite. Recently some bugs got through on a project I was working on, stuff I'd like to avoid in the future.